# How do I chain routes (using `~`) which are the results of functions?

Tags: akka-http, spray-routing

```
scala> import akka.http.scaladsl.server._; import Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server._
import Directives._
```

Suppose I have two functions from some type (`Int`, say) to a `Route`:

```
scala> lazy val r1: Int => Route = ???
r1: Int => akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route = <lazy>

scala> lazy val r2: Int => Route = ???
r2: Int => akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route = <lazy>
```

I can compose a route thusly:

```
scala> lazy val composite: Route = path("foo"){ r1(1) } ~ path("bar"){ r2(1) }
composite: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route = <lazy>
```

What I would like to do is use function composition together with the `~` path chaining. That is, I'd love for this to just work:

```
scala> lazy val composite: Int => Route = path("foo")(r1) ~ path("bar")(r2)
```

Except it doesn't :-(

```
<console>:31: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
    (which expands to)  Int => (akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult])
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
    (which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
       lazy val composite: Int => Route = path("foo")(r1) ~ path("bar")(r2)
                                                      ^
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to do this using point-free function composition,. As *Ramon*'s answer below demonstrates, it's easy to do this if you are willing to duplicate the function application (but this is what I want to avoid). That is:

```
lazy val composite: Int => Route 
  = i => path("foo")(r1(i)) ~ path("bar")(r2(i))
```

**NOTE**

Using **scalaz**, I can do this:

```
scala> import akka.http.scaladsl.server._; import Directives._; import scalaz.syntax.monad._; import scalaz.std.function._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server._
import Directives._
import scalaz.syntax.monad._
import scalaz.std.function._

scala> lazy val r1: Int => Route = ???
r1: Int => akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route = <lazy>

scala> lazy val r2: Int => Route = ???
r2: Int => akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route = <lazy>

scala> lazy val composite = for (x <- r1; y <- r2) yield path("foo")(x) ~ path("bar")(y)
composite: Int => akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route = <lazy>
```

Which is so good as it goes but the implicit `ConjunctionMagnet.fromRouteGenerator` in `akka.http.scaladsl.server` gives me cause to think it might be possible in akka-http directly

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to the scalaz example you gave is:

```
lazy val composite: Int => Route = 
  (i) => path("foo")(r1(i)) ~ path("bar")(r2(i))
```

Similarly, you could anonymize the parameter name but that would result in 2 parameters:

```
lazy val composite: (Int,Int) => Route = path("foo")(r1(_)) ~ path("bar")(r2(_))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say this was equivalent. I guess the point of my question is about point-free function composition, sorry I didn't make that more clear

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Two functions are equal if they map all of the same domain values to the same codomain values.  Therefore, my `composite` is equal to your `composite`.  Regarding "the point" of your question, this doesn't come "out of the box" because `Function1` doesn't have a `flatMap` method.

Comment: That is indeed my "point". I was basically asking if, purely using `akka-http`, I was able to do what I want (i.e. function composition). Not sure how familiar you are with `akka-http` but many things *just work* if you only know the magic incantation of imports. I was suggesting that the implicit in `ConjunctionMagnet` gave me cause to hope that what I wanted might indeed be achievable without having to bring scalaz into the mix

Comment: As for equivalence, I meant in the context of my question, they are not equivalent.